# Django use data in a class based view

Tags: django

I have a class-based view in Django.
I have implemented a method get_context_data. A user can log in or update his/her data and is redirected to a class-based view template.
I want the information of the logged-in user inside the class-based view. I'm not rendering the view, just re-directing. Is there any approach like saving the data in memory during computation or global variables so that it can be accessed anywhere in the views.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the user is logging in using the `authenticate`/`login` method, and you have the `SessionMiddleware` loaded as you should, then the user information should be in your `request.user` object.

In a class-based `View` object you can read the `request` like so:

```
class SomeView(View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = self.request.user
        #recommended: check if the user is authenticated, ie, not anonymous.
        if user.is_authenticated:
            check_something(user) #do whatever you need.
```

in the case of `TemplateView` subclasses (I assume, since you mention `get_context_data`) is the same:

```
class SomeTemplateView(TemplateView):
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user and self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            #do something
```

Globals and other things won't work in a Django service, it might work on development, but in production, your user's request could be handler by different python processes altogether and memory won't be shared between them.